# How can I track how many times an "answer" is shown/called through my jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, output

I have a script that works fine. It is a question and answer type of page and the script shows different answers/output based on the selected options.

I want to track how many times a particular answer is called. There are four answers. Here's a script for one of the outputs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("span[id^='answer']").hide();
    $("span[id^='loading']").show();

    $("input[name^='options']").change(function() {
        $("span[id^='answer']").hide();
        if ($("#q1_option1").is(':checked')) {
            if ($("#q2_option1").is(':checked')) {
                if ($("#q3_option3").is(':checked')) {
                    if ($("#q4_option1").is(':checked')) {
                        $("#answer4").show();
                        $("#answer11").show();
                        $("#loading").hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I'm not sure if I'm making any sense but I hope someone can help. Thank you!!

Comment: You can not just define a variable & increment that when the answer called?

Comment: I'm a beginner in jquery lol but how would I do this? And after I do it, how will I view the number of calls?

Comment: track it where? An aggregate for all users or just within page instance? Objective isn't clear. Not even sure what *"answer is called"* even means

Comment: @WilliamNtim tell me, do you need to stay with numbers of calls, even after refreshing the page?

Comment: For using `variables` in `JavaScript`, you can take a look at [This MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Comment: @charlietfl all users. Overall number of times a particular answer has been called.

Comment: @WilliamNtim there is no `server-side` logic here? I mean, I think you need to send back the result to server, am I right?

Comment: You need to do that server side and not enough is known about this quiz. If it is in a submitted form then you need to parse results and store when it is submitted. Question is far too broad without proper details

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use sessionStorage.setItem() and .getItem

```
if ( ! sessionStorage.getItem('answer1_count') ) {

  sessionStorage.setItem('answer1_count',1);

} else {

  var value = sessionStorage.getItem('answer1_count');
  sessionStorage.setItem('answer1_count',parseInt(value) + 1);

}
```

And you insert that after or before the line that shows the Answer. And so you can retrieve the count by calling sessionStorage.getItem() anywhere on your script.

Comment: Why using `session` here?

Comment: so the count won't be wiped out when the browser is refreshed.

Comment: Hi Victor, can you explain how sessionstorage works? I haven't used that before. And also how will I view the number of calls? (email notification, or on-page notification?)

Comment: Victor, I want to view overall counts in general, is this code only for per session?

Comment: If you know PHP programming, sessionStorage is like $_SESSION in PHP data stored in server side whereas sessionStorage is Browser side.

Comment: Ok, so you're asking the wrong way... because you were saying "jQuery"

Comment: If you want to COUNT how many times the answer is shown and be able to RETRIEVE THE COUNT from any other machine. Then you have to do it in serverside. So in your jQuery you have to use AJAX that connects to your server and make the COUNT there.. so you can display the COUNT back to other machines regardless of users location.